# Sorting parent's model the ember way

Tags: ember.js

In a simple, standard ember.js route ...

```
  this.resource('foo', function () {
      this.route('show');
      this.route('new');
  });
```

I have a `foo` template that shows a new button (link to `foo/new` route) and the `foo.bar` data of the `foo` objects (with links to `foo/show` in a sorted way using the `foo` controller)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    sortProperties: [ 'bar:desc' ],
    sortedList: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProperties')
});
```

The routes `foo/show` and `foo/new` do the obvious, nothing special.

I don't need or want a "real" `foo/index` route, since all my navigation needs are catered for in the `foo` route and template. Therefore I want to `transitionTo` from `foo/index` whenever I enter that route to the first (as in given by the sorting above) `foo/show` route (or `foo\new` if there is nothing to show).

I've learned that "the ember way" is to `transitionTo` out of the route, but never ever out of the controller.

Now, my problem is, that I get access to the unsorted data very easily (it's the model of my parent route, that I can access via `modelFor`) and I can sort this "manually", but I'd rather use the already sorted data from my parent's controller. Now, I'm at a bit of a loss which hook to use in the route to be sure that my parent route's controller's computed properties are ready - and it doesn't feel right. So, what would be the ember way to do this?

Edit: Non-working example at http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hujoxigami/2/edit?html,js,output ...

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ :)

Comment: I've added a jsbin. How do I transition from the FooIndexRoute to the **sorted** first foo object. I could implement sorting on the model myself, but that doesn't seem idiomatic ember to me; I'd rather re-use the existing sorting definition. But that isn't available at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `afterModel` hook as you mention in one of your comments.

```
App.FooIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function(posts, transition) {
    if (posts.get('length') > 0) {
      this.transitionTo('foo.show', posts.get('firstObject'));
    }
}
```

And there is nothing wrong with sorting your model before you return it from the `FooRoute`. (Even better if you can receive it already sorted from your API/data storage)

```
App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // not fully functional, just illustrative
    return [{id:1, name:"Hans", detail:"german"},
            {id:3, name:"Henri", detail:"french"},
            {id:2, name:"Harry", detail:"english"}].sortBy('name');
  }
});
```

The sorting properties in the controller remain relevant if you want to provide sorting controls for the user.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes. Working example (dropped the desc): http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rezozizato/1/edit?html,js,output 

What I was missing was that (a) the controller sorting features are targeted at the use for user controlts and that (b) sorting in the model hook is that easy.